# Twilio's twilio.device is setting up but breaking my React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio

I'm in the process of creating a Twilio Client component for my React-Redux app but am running into a issue with twilio.Device.Setup(). I'm running it with debug on and the log shows the stream is ready and device on but my component fails to render with a TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined. I am running Material UI and  wrapping my component withStyles() for classes which I believe is causing the problem but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any assistance would be appreciated from.

Here's my function

```
export function twilioSetup() {
const token = localStorage.getItem('twilioToken');
if(!token) {
    console.log('Twilio Calls Unavailable');
    return;
};
let device = twilio.Device.setup(token, {
    codecPreferences: ['opus', 'pcmu'],
    fakeLocalDTMF: true,
    debug: true
});

device.on('ready',function () {
    console.log('Twilio.Device Ready!');
  });

device.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log('Twilio.Device Error: ' + error.message);
  });

device.on('connect', function (conn) {
    console.log('Successfully established call!');
  });

device.on('disconnect', function (conn) {
    console.log('Call ended.');
  });

};
```

And here's the error referencing withStyles().

> The above error occurred in the  component:
>       in TwilioCall (created by WithStyles(TwilioCall))
>       in WithStyles(TwilioCall) (created by ConnectFunction)
>       in ConnectFunction (at App.js:7)
>       in div (at App.js:6)
>       in App (at src/index.js:11)
>       in Provider (at src/index.js:10)

Comment: Also if it helps the error occurs right after the Device.debug logs "No WebSocket to clean up." to the console.

Comment: So I was able to get my call to go out and connect by moving the setup function from componentDidMount() and make it part of the call function. The error still occurs but the phone call connnects and the component does render. I'd still like to know what is going on with this error though as it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Where do you call that function? Can you edit your question to give the greater context of Twilio Client within your component?